# Get a list of plugins in mysql

Tags: mysql

When i use the command `show plugins` on `mysql` version 5.0 i get the following error:

```
> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
> manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
> syntax to use near 'plugins' at line 1
```

I get a proper output when i use this command on newer versions.

Is there an option to get a list of plugins on that version of `mysql`? I didn't manage to find that in the web.

Comment: Does MySQL have plug-ins?

Comment: @Omri you need to use INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PLUGINS table read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/plugins-table.html

Comment: @RaymondNijland yeah, but MySQL v5.0 does not have the `plugins` view either. The statement and the view go hand-in-hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is very simple: MySQL plugin API was [introduced in MySQL v5.1](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19078-01/mysql/mysql-refman-5.1/extending-mysql.html#plugin-api), it is not available in any earlier versions:

> MySQL 5.1 and up supports a plugin API that enables creation of server components.

MySQL v5.0 does not include the [show plugins](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19078-01/mysql/mysql-refman-5.0/sql-syntax.html#show) statement, neither the `plugins` view in the [information_schema](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19078-01/mysql/mysql-refman-5.0/information-schema.html).

Therefore there is no way to list plugins in v5.0 because they did not exist.

Comment: Thank you. I suspected that is not supported on old versions. Thanks for the confirmation.